# Translating C code using OpenSSL for public-key authentication to VisualBasic.NET using system.security.cryptography?

Tags: c, vb.net, cryptography

I am trying to mimic the results of some C code that uses the OpenSSL library using the system.security.crytography library in the .net 3.5 world, and I can't seem to get it right.  I need some help... part of the issue is my understanding of crytography in general.

Here's what is supposed to happen:

1. I send a request for authentication to a device.
2. It returns a challenge digest, which I then need to sign with a known key and return
3. The device returns a "success" or "Fail" message.

I have the following code snippet that I am trying to "copy":

```
  //Seed the PRNG
  //Cheating here - the PRNG will be seeded when we create a key pair
  //The key pair is discarded only doing this to seed the PRNG.
  DSA *temp_dsa = DSA_new();
  if(!temp_dsa)
  {
     printf("Error:  The client had an error with the DSA API\n");
     exit(0);
  }

  unsigned char seed[20] = "Our Super Secret Key";
  temp_dsa = DSA_generate_parameters(128, seed, sizeof(seed), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  DSA_free(temp_dsa);


  //A pointer to the private key.
  p = (unsigned char *)&priv_key;

  //Create and allocate a DSA structure from the private key.
  DSA *priv_dsa = NULL;
  priv_dsa = d2i_DSAPrivateKey(NULL, &p, sizeof(priv_key));
  if(!priv_dsa)
  {
     printf("Error:  The client had an error with the DSA API\n");
     exit(0);
  }


  //Allocate memory for the to be computed signature.
  sigret = OPENSSL_malloc(DSA_size(priv_dsa));

  //Sign the challenge digest recieved from the ISC.
  retval = DSA_sign(0, pResp->data, pResp->data_length, sigret, &siglen, priv_dsa);
```

A few more bits of information:

1. priv_key is a 252 element character array of hex characters that is included.
2. The end result is a 512 (or less) array of characters to send back for validation to the device.

Rasmus asked to see the key array.  Here it is:

```
unsigned char priv_key[] = {0x30, 0x81, 0xf9, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00,
0x02, 0x41, 0x00, 0xfe, 0xca, 
0x97, 0x55, 0x1f, 0xc0, 0xb7, 
0x1f, 0xad, 0xf0, 0x93, 0xec, 
0x4b, 0x31, 0x94, 0x78, 0x86, 
0x82, 0x1b, 0xab, 0xc4, 0x9e, 
0x5c, 0x40, 0xd9, 0x89, 0x7d, 
0xde, 0x43, 0x38, 0x06, 0x4f, 
0x1b, 0x2b, 0xef, 0x5c, 0xb7, 
0xff, 0x21, 0xb1, 0x11, 0xe6, 
0x9a, 0x81, 0x9a, 0x2b, 0xef, 
0x3a, 0xbb, 0x5c, 0xea, 0x76, 
0xae, 0x3a, 0x8b, 0x92, 0xd2, 
0x7c, 0xf1, 0x89, 0x8e, 0x4d, 
0x3f, 0x0d, 0x02, 0x15, 0x00, 
0x88, 0x16, 0x1b, 0xf5, 0xda, 
0x43, 0xee, 0x4b, 0x58, 0xbb, 
0x93, 0xea, 0x4e, 0x2b, 0xda, 
0xb9, 0x17, 0xd1, 0xff, 0x21, 
0x02, 0x41, 0x00, 0xf6, 0xbb, 
0x45, 0xea, 0xda, 0x72, 0x39, 
0x4f, 0xc1, 0xdd, 0x02, 0xb4, 
0xf3, 0xaa, 0xe5, 0xe2, 0x76, 
0xc7, 0xdc, 0x34, 0xb2, 0x0a, 
0xd8, 0x69, 0x63, 0xc3, 0x40, 
0x2c, 0x58, 0xea, 0xa6, 0xbd, 
0x24, 0x8b, 0x6b, 0xaa, 0x4b, 
0x41, 0xfc, 0x5f, 0x21, 0x02, 
0x3c, 0x27, 0xa9, 0xc7, 0x7a, 
0xc8, 0x59, 0xcd, 0x5b, 0xdd, 
0x6c, 0x44, 0x48, 0x86, 0xd1, 
0x34, 0x46, 0xb0, 0x89, 0x55, 
0x50, 0x87, 0x02, 0x41, 0x00, 
0x80, 0x29, 0xc6, 0x4a, 0x08, 
0x3e, 0x30, 0x54, 0x71, 0x9b, 
0x95, 0x49, 0x55, 0x17, 0x70, 
0xc7, 0x96, 0x65, 0xc8, 0xc2, 
0xe2, 0x8a, 0xe0, 0x5d, 0x9f, 
0xe4, 0xb2, 0x1f, 0x20, 0x83, 
0x70, 0xbc, 0x88, 0x36, 0x03, 
0x29, 0x59, 0xcd, 0xc7, 0xcd, 
0xd9, 0x4a, 0xa8, 0x65, 0x24, 
0x6a, 0x77, 0x8a, 0x10, 0x88, 
0x0d, 0x2f, 0x15, 0x4b, 0xbe, 
0xba, 0x13, 0x23, 0xa1, 0x73, 
0xa3, 0x04, 0x37, 0xc9, 0x02, 
0x14, 0x06, 0x8e, 0xc1, 0x41, 
0x40, 0xf1, 0xf6, 0xe1, 0xfa, 
0xfb, 0x64, 0x28, 0x02, 0x15, 
0xce, 0x47, 0xaa, 0xce, 0x6e, 
0xfe};
```

Can anyone help me translate this code to it's VB.net crypto equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, the code below does not work. .NET requires additional values in the DSAParameters. I added a comment with another suggestion about BouncyCastle.NET.

---

Sorry, I can't write VB.NET, but you can probably translate the following C# code:

```
DSAParameters keyValue = new DSAParameters();
keyValue.P = new byte[]{0xfe, 0xca, 0x97, 0x55, 0x1f, 0xc0, 0xb7, 0x1f, 0xad, 0xf0, 0x93, 0xec, 0x4b, 0x31, 0x94, 0x78, 0x86, 0x82, 0x1b, 0xab, 0xc4, 0x9e, 0x5c, 0x40, 0xd9, 0x89, 0x7d, 0xde, 0x43, 0x38, 0x06, 0x4f, 0x1b, 0x2b, 0xef, 0x5c, 0xb7, 0xff, 0x21, 0xb1, 0x11, 0xe6, 0x9a, 0x81, 0x9a, 0x2b, 0xef, 0x3a, 0xbb, 0x5c, 0xea, 0x76, 0xae, 0x3a, 0x8b, 0x92, 0xd2, 0x7c, 0xf1, 0x89, 0x8e, 0x4d, 0x3f, 0x0d};
keyValue.Q = new byte[]{0x88, 0x16, 0x1b, 0xf5, 0xda, 0x43, 0xee, 0x4b, 0x58, 0xbb, 0x93, 0xea, 0x4e, 0x2b, 0xda, 0xb9, 0x17, 0xd1, 0xff, 0x21};
keyValue.G = new byte[]{0xf6, 0xbb, 0x45, 0xea, 0xda, 0x72, 0x39, 0x4f, 0xc1, 0xdd, 0x02, 0xb4, 0xf3, 0xaa, 0xe5, 0xe2, 0x76, 0xc7, 0xdc, 0x34, 0xb2, 0x0a, 0xd8, 0x69, 0x63, 0xc3, 0x40, 0x2c, 0x58, 0xea, 0xa6, 0xbd, 0x24, 0x8b, 0x6b, 0xaa, 0x4b, 0x41, 0xfc, 0x5f, 0x21, 0x02, 0x3c, 0x27, 0xa9, 0xc7, 0x7a, 0xc8, 0x59, 0xcd, 0x5b, 0xdd, 0x6c, 0x44, 0x48, 0x86, 0xd1, 0x34, 0x46, 0xb0, 0x89, 0x55, 0x50, 0x87};
keyValue.X = new byte[]{0x80, 0x29, 0xc6, 0x4a, 0x08, 0x3e, 0x30, 0x54, 0x71, 0x9b, 0x95, 0x49, 0x55, 0x17, 0x70, 0xc7, 0x96, 0x65, 0xc8, 0xc2, 0xe2, 0x8a, 0xe0, 0x5d, 0x9f, 0xe4, 0xb2, 0x1f, 0x20, 0x83, 0x70, 0xbc, 0x88, 0x36, 0x03, 0x29, 0x59, 0xcd, 0xc7, 0xcd, 0xd9, 0x4a, 0xa8, 0x65, 0x24, 0x6a, 0x77, 0x8a, 0x10, 0x88, 0x0d, 0x2f, 0x15, 0x4b, 0xbe, 0xba, 0x13, 0x23, 0xa1, 0x73, 0xa3, 0x04, 0x37, 0xc9};
keyValue.Y = new byte[]{0x06, 0x8e, 0xc1, 0x41, 0x40, 0xf1, 0xf6, 0xe1, 0xfa, 0xfb, 0x64, 0x28, 0x02, 0x15, 0xce, 0x47, 0xaa, 0xce, 0x6e, 0xfe};

using (DSACryptoServiceProvider key = new DSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
  key.ImportParameters(keyValue);
  byte[] res = key.SignData(data);
}
```

Your priv_key array of hex-characters is an ASN.1 DER encoded DSA private key (in OpenSSL's non-standard format). Here is a dump, you can probably see where I got the values from:

```
   0 30  249: SEQUENCE {
   3 02    1:   INTEGER 0
   6 02   65:   INTEGER
            :     00 FE CA 97 55 1F C0 B7 1F AD F0 93 EC 4B 31 94
            :     78 86 82 1B AB C4 9E 5C 40 D9 89 7D DE 43 38 06
            :     4F 1B 2B EF 5C B7 FF 21 B1 11 E6 9A 81 9A 2B EF
            :     3A BB 5C EA 76 AE 3A 8B 92 D2 7C F1 89 8E 4D 3F
            :     0D
  73 02   21:   INTEGER
            :     00 88 16 1B F5 DA 43 EE 4B 58 BB 93 EA 4E 2B DA
            :     B9 17 D1 FF 21
  96 02   65:   INTEGER
            :     00 F6 BB 45 EA DA 72 39 4F C1 DD 02 B4 F3 AA E5
            :     E2 76 C7 DC 34 B2 0A D8 69 63 C3 40 2C 58 EA A6
            :     BD 24 8B 6B AA 4B 41 FC 5F 21 02 3C 27 A9 C7 7A
            :     C8 59 CD 5B DD 6C 44 48 86 D1 34 46 B0 89 55 50
            :     87
 163 02   65:   INTEGER
            :     00 80 29 C6 4A 08 3E 30 54 71 9B 95 49 55 17 70
            :     C7 96 65 C8 C2 E2 8A E0 5D 9F E4 B2 1F 20 83 70
            :     BC 88 36 03 29 59 CD C7 CD D9 4A A8 65 24 6A 77
            :     8A 10 88 0D 2F 15 4B BE BA 13 23 A1 73 A3 04 37
            :     C9
 230 02   20:   INTEGER
            :     06 8E C1 41 40 F1 F6 E1 FA FB 64 28 02 15 CE 47
            :     AA CE 6E FE
            :   }
```

Likewise the output from `SignData` might not be in the format you expect. I think OpenSSL puts the result in an ASN.1 DER-container. It will look like this:

```
3082[2 bytes for length of remaining data]
  0281[1 byte for length of this data][some bytes with first half of signature]
  0281[1 byte for length of this data][some bytes with second half of signature]
```

.NET just concatenates the two halves of the signature.

Comment: I added the key array to the inital posting, as it was too large for a comment.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, I've tried what you suggested (both in VB and C#, thinking I was performing the conversion wrong) and it is not working correctly.  I get an exception during ImportParameters that says nothing more than "Bad Data".

I have asked the originating company if they can provide the ey in standard ASN.1 format, but do you have any other suggestions?

Thanks,

Glenn

Comment: It looks like .NET requires the Seed, J and Counter values, which are not included in the OpenSSL-code. You could try using BouncyCastle.Net instead. You want to create a DsaKeyParameters with a DsaPrivateKeyParameters inside, then feed that to a DsaSigner.

Answer (score 1):

Are you dying to code your own solution?  If not, check out [SharpSsh](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sharpssh.aspx?msg=3054576) or the [.NET samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa308954%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get something working... here's what I ended up doing.

I added a few lines to the original C program:

```
  //Create and allocate a DSA structure from the private key.
  DSA *priv_dsa = NULL;
  priv_dsa = d2i_DSAPrivateKey(NULL, &p, sizeof(priv_key));
  if(!priv_dsa)
  {
     printf("Error:  The client had an error with the DSA API\n");
     exit(0);
  }

  printf("create file pointer\n");
  FILE *fp1 = NULL;
  printf("Open file pointer\n");
  if((fp1 = fopen("PrivateKey.pem", "w+"))== NULL)
  {
    printf("opening %s \n", 's', "test failed\n");
  }
  printf("Ready to save\n");
  int i = PEM_write_DSAPrivateKey(fp1, priv_dsa, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
  printf("Closing the file\n");
  int j = fclose(fp1);
```

This saved the key in PEM format.

In my .net application, I used [OpenSSL.Net](http://openssl-net.sourceforge.net/) to try to get as close to the library that was used in the original program as I could without having to Marshall data back and forth to C functions:

```
'Set up the DSA object to sign the digest
Dim myDSA As New DSA(128, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Our Super Secret Key"), 20, Nothing, Nothing)
Dim objReader As New StreamReader("SNMPUnlock.pem")

Dim strKey As String = objReader.ReadToEnd

objReader.Close()
myDSA = DSA.FromPrivateKey(strKey)

'Create the second Request packet with the signed digest
myRequestPacket = New dcISCValidatePacket
With myRequestPacket
    .ResponseID = dcISCValidatePacket.dcCommandResponseID.ISCValidateGUI
    .Data = myDSA.Sign(myResponsePacket.Data)
End With
```

It is all working correctly now.  Thank you for your help... it pointed me in the right direction...

Thanks again,

Glenn